# Update trigger with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers, group-by

I'm using insert-/update triggers to update a second table's column `Price`.

The insert trigger seems to work perfectly, but when I try to change a single record in SSMS, I get an error:

> The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row
>   unique or they alter multiple rows(2 rows).

This is my update-trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdateMasterData] ON [dbo].[tabSparePartMasterData_Temp]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

UPDATE    tabSparePart
SET      Price = MD.Price
FROM    tabSparePart INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT     inserted.[Material Number (SAP)] AS MaterialNumber, inserted.Price
    FROM          inserted
    GROUP BY [Material Number (SAP)], inserted.Price
) MD 
ON tabSparePart.SparePartName = MD.MaterialNumber
```

I need to group by Material-Number because there are redundant rows inserted into table `tabSparePartMasterData_Temp` which i'm only using to update the Sparepart-Price in `tabSparePart`. But i assumed that the group by would sort out the duplicates(Price is same for any duplicate).

It's possible that the inserted/updated records' `MaterialNumber` is not available in `tabSparepart`. In this case this record should be "skipped". Does the `INNER JOIN` takes that into account?

Comment: What generates the error message please? It doesn't look like SQL...

Comment: Is there by chance a unique constraint on `(tabSparePart.Price)` or on `(tabSparePart.SparePartName, tabSparePart.Price)`? If there are two or more identical `tabSparePart.SparePartName`, your update can violate the constraint, and maybe that's what actually happened.

Comment: @gbn: SQL-Server Management-Studio (SSMS) when i try to change a price value in the table with the trigger.

Comment: Please add table definitions please and the update code

Comment: @Andriy: Yes, the is a unique contstraint on `tabSparePart.SparePartName`. But i don't want to insert records there but only update the related price.

Comment: @Tim: If `SparePartName` is unique and `Price` not necessarily then it's not what I thought. And answering your question about `MaterialNumber` not available in `tabSparepart`, yes, INNER JOIN takes that into account by yielding an empty row set, so no update can take place then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the trigger

This error doesn't look like a SQL error and I'm guessing the client code is getting confused by the 2nd update in the trigger.

Edit: this error can be caused by the data grid view in SSMS being silly.

This isn't a SQL message as I thought: it is an SSMS being stupid message

See these which all says "learn to write SQL"

- http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/dealing-with-the-row-value-s-updated-or (Less than dot blog)
- [Trigger that modifies multiple rows on diffrent table then it was invoked on in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901931/trigger-that-modifies-multiple-rows-on-diffrent-table-then-it-was-invoked-on-in-s)
- [SSMS permits duplicate records in a table, but not subsequent updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092775/sql-server-management-studio-quirks-allowing-things-it-shouldnt-and-then-screa)

Saying that, there is a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925719) about a bug in SQL Server 2005...

Comment: I've changed the trigger to `SET NOCOUNT ON` but the error is the same. What do you mean with "2nd update"? I'm updating a different table than the table which belongs to this trigger.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: there are *two* updates here even if on different tables. Some clients get confused by this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage

Comment: You are right. I added the `NOCOUNT` at the top of the trigger but i had to insert it straight above the `UPDATE`. Thank you.